# C++: std:endl VS \n

Tags: c++

Tengo entendido que la única diferencia entre las dos formas de hacer una nueva línea, es que la primera además, vacía el buffer de salida.
¿Podrían mostrarme un ejemplo práctico donde se vea la diferencia en usar uno y otro?

Comment: Prácticamente es solo en determinados casos donde obtienes la diferencia de uno y otro, dado que el rendimiento no es el mismo, es decir, no es lo mismo finalizar un string con un caracter mas (`'\n'`) que llamar a `ostream` solo por imprimir un salto de linea. Lo que deja tu pregunta resuelta en su formulación. En teoría _(porque no lo he probado)_ la diferencia entre `std::endl` y `'\n'` es de milésimas de segundo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, aunque puede ser que la haya formulado incorrectamente. No hablo sobre cuál de la dos es más efectiva en cuanto a rendimiento, sino, hay algún caso donde usar una otra arroje diferentes resultados? Algún ejemplo donde se pueda ver esa diferencia?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tomado de [aquí](http://demin.ws/blog/english/2012/04/25/endl-vs-new-line/) y de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n), explicando lo siguiente:

El `'\n'` es un caracter que, llamado "salto de línea" o "lone feed", está representado por parecer null, pero solo posiciona el cursor en una nueva linea para seguir escribiendo.

Mientras que `std::endl` es el equivalente a: `std::cout << "\n" << std::flush`.

Sus diferencias son estrictamente obvias, dado que llamar al caracter `\n` solo involucra concatenar un solo string, pero al hacer uso de `std::endl` se llama a una limpieza del buffer *(que contesta tu pregunta)*.

Los casos donde se pueden utilizar, probemos con el código del primer link:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s(1, 'x');
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {    
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Con las siguientes configuraciones:

```
clang++ -o endl -O3 endl.cpp && time ./endl >rubbish
```

Arroja los siguientes resultados:

```
real    0m4.518s
user    0m1.080s
sys     0m3.311s
```

Mientras que el mismo código solo con el escape:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s(1, 'x');
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Y las mismas configuraciones:

```
clang++ -o endl -O3 endl.cpp && time ./endl >rubbish
```

Produce estos resultados:

```
real    0m0.263s
user    0m0.236s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Los tiempos de respuesta son mucho más efectivos dado que no se *"exige"* que se limpie el buffer.

Esto, claro en un caso *hipotetico* donde no necesites limpiar el buffer de salida, pero como menciono anteriormente, no hay basta diferencia entre ambos, siempre se imprimirá un caracter de escape `\n` para la nueva linea. Lo que deja un último detalle: La unica diferencia es rendimiento.

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, muchas gracias. Una última consulta. En qué casos es necesario limpiar el buffer de salida? No se si corresponde publicarlo acá o hacer una nueva pregunta.

Comment: +1 por comparar el rendimiento al hacer `flush` a el buffer

Comment: @user2763052 Tomalo de la siguiente manera, imagina que tienes un programa que lee un archivo de mas de 500,000 lineas, pero tienes una memoria limitada, no puedes leer las 500,000 de golpe, sino que lees las primeras 50,000, luego limpias el buffer de entrada y de salida para poder cargar las siguientes 50,000 lineas y así sucesivamente hasta terminar.

Comment: Perfecto. Ahora lo entendí, muchas gracias por la explicación.

Comment: Una consulta, el llamado "retorno de carro" no es el caracter `\r`? Según tengo entendido, al caracter `\n` se le llama "nueva línea".

Comment: @Xam Yup, he confundido los terminos :P Era salto de linea xd