# C++ con vectores

Tags: c++

Buenas me pidieron desarrollar un programa que permita imprimir la suma, el producto, el máximo y el mínimo de 5 números enteros. Lo desarrollé pero al momento que me imprime el menor siempre me sale que es 2(así no ingrese el número 2). Si pudieran revisar y decirme mi error. Gracias.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio>

int main () {

       int vector[5];
       int i;
       int suma=0, producto=1, mayor=vector[0], menor=vector[0];
       for (i=0; i<5; i++){
          cout<<"Ingrese el numero "<<(i+1)<<endl;
          cin>> vector[i];
       }
       for (i=0; i<5; i++){
         if (vector[i]> mayor){
            mayor=vector[i];
         }
         if (vector[i]< menor){
            menor=vector[i];
         }
       }
       for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
           suma=suma+vector[i];
       }
       for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
          producto=producto*vector[i];
       }
       cout<<"La suma es: "<<suma<<endl;
       cout<<"El producto es: "<<producto<<endl;
       cout<<"El mayor es: "<<mayor<<endl;
       cout<<"El menor es: "<<menor<<endl;

       getch();
       return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inicializa el menor y el mayor despues del ingreso de  los números

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <conio.h>

        int main () {

           int vector[5];
           int i;
           int suma=0, producto=1, mayor, menor;
           for (i=0; i<5; i++){
              cout<<"Ingrese el numero "<<(i+1)<<endl;
              cin>> vector[i];
           }
           **mayor=vector[0];
           menor=vector[0];**

           for (i=0; i<5; i++){
             if (vector[i]> mayor){
                mayor=vector[i];
             }
             if (vector[i]< menor){
                menor=vector[i];
             }
           }
           for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
               suma=suma+vector[i];
           }
           for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
              producto=producto*vector[i];
           }
           cout<<"La suma es: "<<suma<<endl;
           cout<<"El producto es: "<<producto<<endl;
           cout<<"El mayor es: "<<mayor<<endl;
           cout<<"El menor es: "<<menor<<endl;

           getch();
           return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Pese a que la respuesta de [Mauricio Brito](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/15020/2742) señala la solución, hay detalles que se han omitido y que vale la pena mencionar.

#### Sólo cuatro de seis variables inicializadas.

```
int vector[5];
int i;
int suma=0, producto=1, mayor=vector[0], menor=vector[0];
```

Tanto `vector` como `i` carecen de valor(es) inicial(es), sería aconsejable dar un valor a las variables no inicializadas:

```
int vector[5] {}; // todos los elementos del arreglo vector contienen 0
int i = 0;
int suma=0, producto=1, mayor=vector[0], menor=vector[0];
```

¿Por qué es tan importante dar estos valores iniciales? Porque de no acerlo, obtienen *valores residuales* desde la memoria y estos pueden afectar al funcionamiento del programa... por ejemplo:

> al momento que me imprime el menor siempre me sale que es 2(así no ingrese el número 2).

Apuesto que el arreglo `vector` obtuvo varios valores desde la memoria y en la posición `0` tendría un `2`, por esto, al inicializar `menor` esta variable obtiene ese valor residual y dicho valor residual es menor a cualquiera de los que introduces.

Dado que la variable `i` la usas más adelante y lo primero que haces con ella es otorgarle un valor no sería necesario inicializarla; aún así yo acosejo hacerlo.

#### No escoges los mejores valores para inicializar `mayor` y `menor`.

Incluso aunque hubieras otorgado valor a los elementos del arreglo `vector`, ninguno de esos valores es la mejor elección para `mayor` o `menor`; las mejores elecciones son respectivamente el menor número entero y el mayor número entero, los cuales puedes obtener con la cabecera `<limits>`:

```
int vector[5] {}; // todos los elementos del arreglo vector contienen 0
int i = 0;
int suma = 0, producto = 1;
int mayor = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); // Menor entero posible
int menor = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // Mayor entero posible
```

Estas elecciones para inicializar `mayor` y `menor` te garantizan que sea cual sea el valor de entrada cualquier valor será mayor al que ya contiene `mayor` y menor al que ya contiene `menor`.

#### No necesitas el arreglo ni tres de los bucles `for`.

¿Por qué hacer las cosas en dos pasos pudiendo hacerlas en uno?

```
int suma = 0, producto = 1;
int mayor = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
int menor = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){ // i declarado y usado solo aqui
    std::cout << "Ingrese el numero " << (i + 1) << '\n';
    int numero = 0;
    std::cin >> numero;
    mayor = std::max(mayor, numero); // std::max pertenece a la libreria <algorithm>
    menor = std::min(menor, numero); // std::min pertenece a la libreria <algorithm>
    suma += numero;
    producto *= numero;
}
```

Con estos cambios el programa se comporta igual y pasas de usar cuatro bucles `for` a usar tan sólo uno, así que el ordenador trabaja menos.

Además, usando algunas de las funciones de la cabecera de algoritmos ([`<algorithm>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)) seleccionas de manera más fácil el número mayor y menor:

- [`std::max`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max): Te devuelve el número mayor de los que le pasas por parámetros.
- [`std::min`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min): Te devuelve el número menor de los que le pasas por parámetros.

Usar estas funciones y eliminar algunas líneas, hace el código algo más legible.

#### Usas cabeceras innecesarias que además no son de C++.

Estás incluyendo la cabecera [`<conio>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) que forma parte de [c](/questions/tagged/c) y su misión es comunicarse con la consola a la vez que incluyes la cabecera [`<iostream>`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iostream) la cuál tiene exáctamente la misma misión pero siendo esta última de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), el programa ni siquiera debería compilar tal y como lo has compartido.

Las cabeceras de C++ no tienen extensión de archivo: `<iostream>`, `<vector>`, `<string>`, etc... excepto las cabeceras que existen por compatibilidad con C: `<math.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, etc...

La mayoría de cabeceras de `C` disponen de una versión *portada* a `C++` a la que se le ha quitado la extensión, se les ha añadido el prefijo "c" (por ejemplo `<cmath>`, `<cstdint>`) y han sido adaptadas a `C++`. Si estás trabajando con `C++` deberías usar estas últimas no las de `C`.

#### Te falta el espacio de nombres.

Antes de `cin` y `cout` te falta el espacio de nombres, sin ello el programa no compila; puedes ahorrarte escribir el `std::` contínuamente escribiendo la instrucción `using namespace std`. Te aconsejo que eches un vistazo a [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%c3%a9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%c3%a1ctica) para conocer más detalles.

#### Abusas de `std::endl`.

Normalmente no es buena idea, te aconsejo echar un vistazo a [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14969/c-stdendl-vs-n) para conocer más detalles.

---

Con todas las correcciones sugeridas aplicadas, el código [[quedaría así]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2bb7NxVtm5I87UiH):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    int suma = 0, producto = 1;
    int mayor = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int menor = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Ingrese el numero " << (i + 1) << '\n';
        int numero = 0;
        std::cin >> numero;
        mayor = std::max(mayor, numero);
        menor = std::min(menor, numero);
        suma += numero;
        producto *= numero;
    }

    std::cout << "La suma es: "     << suma     << '\n'
              << "El producto es: " << producto << '\n'
              << "El mayor es: "    << mayor    << '\n'
              << "El menor es: "    << menor    << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Por cierto, en los bucles `for` [usa pre-incremento siempre que te sea posible](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/).