# Inicializar arreglos de objetos en C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Quisiera hacer un arreglo en C++ de tipo Punto, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <windows.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Punto.h"
#include "Linea.h"

Punto *vertices[2] = new Punto[2];

void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-200, 200, -200, 200);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    vertices[0] = new Punto(10.0, 25.0);

    Linea *l = new Linea(p1, p2);
    l->dibuja();


    delete l;

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);//SE INIZIALIZA LAS VARIABLES DE ENTORNO EN UN SOLO BUFFER Y COLOREA RGB
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);// se define el tamaño de la ventana
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,50); // se define las coordenadas inicilaes donde aparacera la ventana
    glutCreateWindow("Parcial_1");//crea una ventana y se le coloca una leyenda hola mundo
    init();                          //Funcion de servicio para inizializar parametros del ambiente grafico
    glutDisplayFunc(display);          // se define cula es la funcion que redibujara el ambiente grafico
    //glutIdleFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Código de Punto.h

```
#ifndef PUNTO_H
#define PUNTO_H

class Punto
{
    public:
        double x, y;

    public:
        Punto(double x, double y);
        void dibuja(void);
        virtual ~Punto();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // PUNTO_H
```

Código de Punto.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "Punto.h"

Punto::Punto(double x, double y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

void Punto::dibuja(void)
{
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2d(x, y);
    glEnd();
}

Punto::~Punto()
{
    //dtor
}
```

El error es aquí

```
Punto *vertices[2] = new Punto[2];
```

El error que marca es "no maching function for call 'Punto::Punto()'"
Y quisiera saber si la incialización de se puede hacer como se hace en Java o C#

Comment: por que es `Punto *vertices[2] = new Punto[2];` y no `Punto *vertices = new Punto[2];`?? Me parece sospechoso :P

Comment: Modifiqué como me dijiste, pero me sigue macando el mismo error

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de "punto.h"? quizá sirva para saber por que no funciona. Por que creo que tienes un constructor del tipo (x, y) y no uno vacio... por eso te da el error.

Comment: Ya está agregado al demás código :)

Comment: intentaste agregar un constructor vacio `Punto::Punto(){  this->x = 0; this->y = 0; }`?

Comment: Sí, es el de Punto, pero descuida, ya pude solucionarlo. Muchas gracias por ayudarme :D. En breve comento mi solución.

Comment: Una pregunta parecida, [con el mismo problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15367/no-matching-function-for-call-to-classclass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes aquí:

```
Punto *vertices[2] = new Punto[2];
```

Para que eso funcione, tu clase `Punto` **necesita** de un constructor sin parámetros; sin embargo, tu clase **no lo tiene**.

Puede que sepas que C++ *genera* los constructores por ti ... si tú **no generas ninguno**. Como tienes un constructor `Punto::Punto(double x, double y)`, el compilador no genera ninguno, y te muestra el error indicado.

La solución mas fácil es crear tu propio constructor sin argumentos:

> Punto.h

```
#ifndef PUNTO_H
#define PUNTO_H

class Punto
{
    public:
        double x, y;

    public:
        Punto( ); //<- AÑADIMOS ESTO
        Punto(double x, double y);
        void dibuja(void);
        virtual ~Punto();

    protected:

    private:
};
```

> Punto.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "Punto.h"

// AÑADIMOS ESTO. CONSTRUCTOR SIN PARÁMETROS
Punto::Punto( ) : x( 0.0 ), y( 0.0 ) {
}

Punto::Punto(double x, double y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

void Punto::dibuja(void)
{
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2d(x, y);
    glEnd();
}

Punto::~Punto()
{
    //dtor
}
```

Con eso, asignamos los valores `0, 0` a tu Punto, cuando lo creamos sin ningún parámetro en el constructor.

Comment: Oh, ya, eso es una buena idea de hecho :D Muchas gracias por ayudarme :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el compilador espera el operador `()` y no `[]`. Bueno, eso es de entrada, pero la real solución la hice viendo un artículo que dejaré el link aquí:
https://www.foro.lospillaos.es/c-array-de-objetos-vt14173.html

Bueno, en primer lugar, quite el operador `new` seguido de la clase Punto y lo deje tal cual, un arreglo de punteros.

Código

```
#include <windows.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Punto.h"
#include "Linea.h"

Punto *vertices[2];

void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-200, 200, -200, 200);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    vertices[0] = new Punto(10.0, 5.0);
    vertices[1] = new Punto(150, 150);

    Linea *l = new Linea(vertices);
    l->dibuja();


    delete l;

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);//SE INIZIALIZA LAS VARIABLES DE ENTORNO EN UN SOLO BUFFER Y COLOREA RGB
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);// se define el tamaño de la ventana
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,50); // se define las coordenadas inicilaes donde aparacera la ventana
    glutCreateWindow("Parcial_1");//crea una ventana y se le coloca una leyenda hola mundo
    init();                          //Funcion de servicio para inizializar parametros del ambiente grafico
    glutDisplayFunc(display);          // se define cula es la funcion que redibujara el ambiente grafico
    //glutIdleFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Pongo el código de main.cppya que es e único fichero que modifiqué.