# C++ Calculo de filas separadas Matriz

Tags: c++, array

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c, floor, colum;
    float rent;
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t< Sistema de calculo de arriendos >"<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"> Ingrese el valor de la renta: "<<char(36);
    cin>>rent;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"> Ingrese la cantidad de pisos: ";
    cin>>floor;
    cout<<endl<<"> Ingrese la cantidad de habitaciones por piso: ";
    cin>>colum;
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    string edificio[floor][colum];
    int vpiso[floor];
    for (int x=0, y=0; x<floor && y<=colum; y++)
    {
        if (y==colum)
        {
            y=0;
        }
        cout<<"> En el Piso "<<x+1<<" la habitacion "<<y+1<<" esta ocupada? (si/no): ";
        cin>>edificio[x][y];
        cout<<endl;
        if (edificio[x][y]=="si")
        {
            c++;
        }
        if (y==colum-1)
        {
            x++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t";
    for (int x=0, y=0; x<floor && y<=colum; y++)
    {
        if (y==colum)
        {
            y=0;
        }
        cout<<edificio[x][y]<<"\t";
        if (y==colum-1)
        {
            x++;
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t";
        }
    }
    cout<<endl<<"> Debe cobrar a "<<c<<" personas un valor de: "<<char(36)<<rent*c;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

PD: Rehice el programa de 0, pero lo que quiero es mostrar por pantalla es el valor a cobrar por cada fila

**ej:**

*"En el piso 1 deben" x personas "y tienen que pagar" x valor*

*"En el piso 2 deben" x personas "y tienen que pagar" x valor*

Comment: Y cual es el error? que esperas obtener? Cual es exactamente el problema? que intentas solucionar?

Comment: El problema no es el codigo, de funcionar funciona, el problema es al final, el calculo no lo hace correctamente, el problema ya lo explique arriba

Comment: Ademas de que veo muchos problemas con el codigo, sigues sin explicar a que resultado quieres llegar, como quieres llgar a el, y que hace tu codigo. De por si, deberias verificar que valores llegan a media y cmedia, para ver en que punto esta el error. Te aclaro que las matrices se recorren usualmente con dos for anidados, no con un for y montones de switch e if.

Comment: Porfavor intenta explicarnos que es lo que hace el código, cuales son los resultados que esperas con el y la linea exacta donde está fallando.

Comment: Intenta cambiar esto `int calta, cmedia, cbaja;` por `float`.

Comment: @ArtEze rehice el codigo de 0 y mejore ciertas cosas, la cosa es que quiero mostrar el calculo de cada fila y no se como

Comment: @NaCl el problema es al final, rehice el programa pero el problema es que quiero mostrar cada fila por separado, arriba en la pregunta lo explique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto está mal redactado, si dijeras *"tantos"* o *"tantas"*, sería más entendible, pero como pusiste la letra `x` parece como si fuera una variable.

```
"En el piso 1 deben" x personas "y tienen que pagar" x valor.
```

Yo lo cambiaría por esto, ya que no es probable que la cantidad de personas sea la misma que el valor a pagar. La magia está en cambiar el número de piso por el de una variable.

Sospecho que las variables deberían ser...

```
cantidadPisos = floor;
piso = x;
cantidadPersonas = c;
valor = rent*c;
```

El código debe quedar algo así, abajo del `if` que verifica la columna debe ir un `cout` .

```
    if (y==colum-1)
    {
        x++;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t";
    }
    cout << "En el piso " << piso
    <<" deben " << cantidadPersonas << "personas"
    << "y tienen que pagar" << valor << "valor." <<endl;
```

Comment: Pues si.. con x me refiero a cualquier valor, no que x es la que debe enseñar, gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 3):

#### Problema.

Todo. El código que presentas no parece ajustarse, de ninguna manera, a lo que pretendes.

1. `vpiso` no se usa.
2. Usas `std::string` sin incluir `<string>`.
3. Usas `std::cin` para hacer una pregunta binaria a tu usuario, usando una variable de texto para leer y comprobar el resultado.

   - Para empeorarlo más, usas un [arreglo de tamaño variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (no soportados en C++ más que mediante extensiones de compilador) para guardar la respuesta.
4. [Abusas de `std::endl`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14971/2742).
5. Quieres mostrar `"En el piso 1 deben" x personas "y tienen que pagar" x valor` al final y esa cadena ni siquiera forma parte del código.
6. No inicializas ni una variable.

   - Y los nombres de las variables no son auto-explicativos, **no uses variables cuyo nombre sea una sola letra**.

El punto 3 es especialmente preocupante, todas estas respuestas se considerarán negativas:

- `Si`.
- `SI`.
- `Yes`.
- `Da`.
- `sí`.

Mientras que estas respuestas negativas se consierarán positivas:

- `si claro, a ti te lo voy a decir!`.
- `si vuelves a preguntarme algo, me comeré tu pez de colores a la parrilla`.
- `si me entero de que trabajas para Skynet usaré tu CPU de pisapapeles`.

#### Propuesta.

No necesitas un arreglo de dos dimensiones para guardar cada piso/habitación ya que sólo requieres el sumatorio de cada piso, así que usa un arreglo sólo para las habitaciones en que contarás cada piso ocupado.

```
unsigned floor{}, colum{}, *arrendados;
float rent{};
std::cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t< Sistema de calculo de arriendos >\n\n\n";
std::cout<<"> Ingrese el valor de la renta: $";
std::cin>>rent;
std::cout<<'\n';
std::cout<<"> Ingrese la cantidad de pisos: ";
std::cin>>floor;
std::cout<<"\n> Ingrese la cantidad de habitaciones por piso: ";
std::cin>>colum;
std::cout<<"\n\n";

arrendados = new unsigned[floor]{};
```

Los pisos no ocupados no nos importan para el cálculo, así que los ignoramos:

```
for (unsigned piso{}; piso < floor; ++piso)
{
    for (unsigned habitacion{}; habitacion < colum; ++habitacion)
    {
        std::string ocupada{};
        std::cout<<"\n> En el Piso "<<(piso+1)
                 <<" la habitacion "<<(habitacion+1)
                 <<" esta ocupada? (si/no): ";
        std::cin>>ocupada;

        arrendados[piso] += ocupada == "si" ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Para acabar, mostramos los resultados y liberamos la memoria dinámica:

```
for (unsigned piso{}; piso < floor; ++piso)
{
    std::cout << "\nEn el piso " << piso
              << " deben " << arrendados[piso]
              << " personas y tienen que pagar "
              << (arrendados[piso] * rent) << " valor";
}

delete[] arrendados;
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando [[aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fHLY5T5lrW8ovHGx).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sobre lo primero si, no uso vpiso, que lo intentaba usar para calcular el valor x piso, sobre string, bueno tengo entendido que string ya viene incluida en iostream pero no las funciones de la libreria x eso no la uso, y de ahi estudiare todo lo que has señalado gracias x las correciones aunque el ejercicio me exige que haga una matriz

Comment: Si tu pregunta contiene limitaciones o requerimientos especiales **debes mencionarlo**, los demás usuarios no podemos *adivinar* tus requerimientos, debes ayudarnos a ayudarte. `<string>` puede venir incluida en `<iostream>` pero también debes incluir explícitamente lo que usas no confiar en que otras cabeceras lo incluirán por ti.