# C++ - Ouput Diferente (Suma y producto de Vectores)

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de agregar a un tercer vector. La suma y multiplicación de dos vectores diferentes. Sin embargo no puedo entender por qué los valores de salida no son los esperados.

Los métodos que uso son: mostrar, sumar y realizar Producto.

```
void mostrar(int vecAMostrar[], int tamanioVector){
    for(int i = 0; i < tamanioVector ; i++){
        cout << vecAMostrar[i] << endl;
    }
    return;
}

void suma(int vec1[], int vec2[], int vecResultado[], int tamanioAceptado){

    for(int i = 0; i < tamanioAceptado; i++){
        vecResultado[i] = vec1[i] + vec2[i];
    }
    return;
}

void producto(int vec1[], int vec2[], int vecResultado[], int tamanioAceptado){

    for(int i = 0; i < tamanioAceptado; i++){
        vecResultado[i] = vec1[i] * vec2[i];
    }
    return;
}
```

Pero, cuándo los invoco en el main:

```
int main()
{
    int vecUno[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int vecDos[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int vecSuma[] = {};
    int vecProducto[] = {};

    producto(vecUno, vecDos, vecProducto, 5);
    cout << "PRODUCTO" << endl;
    mostrar(vecProducto, 5);

    suma(vecUno, vecDos, vecSuma, 5);
    cout << "SUMA" << endl;
    mostrar(vecSuma, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Lo que obtengo es que el segundo output está mal. ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal en el main o en las funciones?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta que parece que no se esta manejando bien la memoria y vec2 toma los valores de la ultima operación, estuve probando y si los arreglos los creas fijos no tiene problema el resultado final prueba para que te cerciores:

```
int vecUno[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int vecDos[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int vecSuma[5];
int vecProducto[5];
```

Esta son las lineas donde inicializas los vectores.

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias! Me sirvió. Y también me doy cuenta que tengo que profundizar en conocer el tema de "Manejo de memoria". Gracias!

Comment: Pese a que la respuesta es correcta, es a la vez incompleta: falta describir **por qué** arregla el problema... un "*estuve probando*" no es la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando dos características diferentes del lenguaje que combinadas de la manera incorrecta, provocan que tu código de comporte de manera errática.

#### Deducción implícita del tamaño de arreglo.

El lenguaje C++ (y también C) permite omitir el tamaño de un arreglo si al inicializarlo se le dan explícitamente los elementos; en ese caso el compilador contará los elementos ahorrando ese tedio al programador, en tu caso:

```
int vecUno[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Arreglo de 5 elementos, equivale a int vecUno[5] = ...
int vecDos[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Arreglo de 5 elementos, equivale a int vecDos[5] = ...
int vecSuma[] = {}; // Arreglo de CERO elementos
int vecProducto[] = {}; // Arreglo de CERO elementos
```

Dado que al inicializar `vecSuma` y `vecProducto` les has facilitado una lista vacía, el recuento de elementos de dichas listas es cero, así que contienen cero elementos; por otro lado `vecUno` y `vecDos` contienen cinco elementos porque el recuento de elementos de la lista usada para inicializarlos es cinco; en memoria tendrían un aspecto parecido a:

[image]
Como puedes ver, ni `vecSuma` ni `vecProducto` apuntan a espacio en memoria ¡porque tienen 0 elementos!

#### Decaimiento de arreglo a puntero.

Pasar un arreglo a una función sin indicar su tamaño es equivalente a pasar un puntero apuntando al primer elemento del arreglo, así tus funciones `mustrar`, `suma` y `producto` podrían ser reescritas para aceptar punteros sin que su comportamiento se viese afectado:

```
void mostrar(int vecAMostrar *, int tamanioVector);
void suma(int vec1 *, int vec2 *, int vecResultado *, int tamanioAceptado);
void producto(int vec1 *, int vec2 *, int vecResultado *, int tamanioAceptado);
```

Sin embargo, si hubieses especificado el tamaño en el parámetro arreglo de las funciones (en lugar de añadirlo como parámetro adicional) te habría surgido un error en tiempo de compilación:

```
void mostrar(int (&vecAMostrar)[5]) { ... }
void suma(int (&vec1)[5], int (&vec2)[5], int (&vecResultado)[5]) { ... }
void producto(int (&vec1)[5], int (&vec2)[5], int (&vecResultado)[5]) { ... }

int main()
{
    // ...
    producto(vecUno, vecDos, vecProducto);
    mostrar(vecProducto

    // ..
    suma(vecUno, vecDos, vecSuma);
    mostrar(vecProducto

    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> error: ninguna función coincide con la llamada a 'producto'
> producto(vecUno, vecDos, vecProducto);
> ^~~~~~~~
> nota: la función candidata no es viable: no existe conversión conocida de 'int [0]' a 'int (&)[5]' para el 3r parámetro
> void producto(int (&vec1)[5], int (&vec2)[5], int (&vecResultado)[5]){
>                                                    ^
> error: ninguna función coincide con la llamada a 'mostrar'
> mostrar(vecProducto);
> ^~~~~~~
> nota: la función candidata no es viable: no existe conversión conocida de 'int [0]' a 'int (&)[5]' para el 1r parámetro
> void mostrar(int (&vecAMostrar)[5]){
>                   ^
> error: ninguna función coincide con la llamada a 'suma'
> suma(vecUno, vecDos, vecSuma);
> ^~~~
> nota: la función candidata no es viable: no existe conversión conocida de 'int [0]' a 'int (&)[5]' para el 3r parámetro
> void suma(int (&vec1)[5], int (&vec2)[5], int (&vecResultado)[5]){
>                                                ^
> ```

Al pasar los parámetros como referencia a arreglo de tamaño determinado (ese extraño parámetro de *`tipo (&nombre)[tamaño]`*) evitamos que el arreglo decaiga a puntero y entonces el compilador se ve obligado a comprobar si el parámetro pasado coincide con el parámetro esperado; como podemos ver en los errores no coincide: un arreglo de ningún elemento no es un arreglo de cinco elementos.

#### ¿Qué ha pasado en tu programa?

Hemos visto que `vecSuma` y `vecProducto` no apuntan a ningún espacio en memoria (claro, tienen cero elementos) así que al indexarlos y escribir sobre ellos estás forzando en el programa un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) que podría hacer que el programa funcionase sin errores visibles, o podría provocar una corrupción de memoria (mostrando valores erróneos), o podría borrar tu disco duro, provocar la tercera guerra mundial o invocar [demonios dentro de tus fosas nasales](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

#### ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Como ya ha comentado [Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/95226/2742) una posible solución es asignar tamaño a los arreglos de destino (aunque no ha explicado por qué esto lo soluciona) de esta manera esquivas el comportamiento indefinido ya que los arreglos `vecSuma` y `vecProducto` apuntarán a un espacio de memoria suficientemente grande para asignar los resultados de las operaciones; si vas a usar arreglos de tamaño prefijado yo además aconsejaría usar el tipo de estos arreglos como tipo de los parámetros, consiguiendo de esta manera que el compilador detecte los errores en tiempo de compilación:

```
using cinco_enteros = int[5];

void mostrar(const cinco_enteros &vecAMostrar){
    for (const auto &valor : vecAMostrar) {
        std::cout << valor << '\n';
    }
}

void suma(const cinco_enteros &vec1, const cinco_enteros &vec2, cinco_enteros &vecResultado){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        vecResultado[i] = vec1[i] + vec2[i];
    }
}

void producto(const cinco_enteros &vec1, const cinco_enteros &vec2, cinco_enteros &vecResultado){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        vecResultado[i] = vec1[i] * vec2[i];
    }
}
```

En el código anterior hemos definido un alias para el tipo `int[5]` (un arreglo de cinco enteros) y lo usamos para declarar los parámetros de las funciones, puedes ver el código funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hfKUlq1XZy1ztGNq); fíjate que además los parámetros que se usarán sólo para ser leídos son pasados como constantes, esto es considerado una buena práctica; también ten en cuenta que he eliminado la instrucción `return` del final de las funciones, no es necesaria pues la función ya iba a acabar igualmente.

Otra alternativa, conociendo el tamaño de antemano, es usar un [`std::array<int, 5>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) en lugar de un `int[5]`.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Favorece cuando sea posible (casi siempre) el pre-incremento al post-incremento, lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para más detalles.
- En un programa tan corto no tendrás muchos problemas, pero en la medida de lo posible evita `using namespace std;` en cabeceras (no aplica en tu caso), lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%c3%a9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%c3%a1ctica) para saber por qué.
- Favorece el uso de `\n` frente a `std::endl` cuando sea posible (casi siempre), lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14969/c-stdendl-vs-n) para saber por qué.