# ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Valores erróneos guardados en una matriz

Tags: c++

Me he topado con un error un poco particular con las matrices.

El programa pide al usuario el numero de filas, después el numero de columnas que va a tener la matriz; luego pide a usuario que inserte los valores para rellenar la matriz.

El error viene al intentar imprimir los elementos de la matriz: Cuando la matriz tiene 3 columnas y 3 filas, presenta números erróneos que nunca se guardaron.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<locale.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int cafi,caco,vael;
    cout<<"Cantidad de filas que desea"<<endl;
    cin>>cafi;
    cout<<"Cantidad de columnas que desea"<<endl;
    cin>>caco;
    for(int i=0; i < cafi; i++){
        int array[cafi][caco];
        for(int o=0; o < caco; o++){
            cout<<"Valor del elemento situado en la fila "<<i<<" columna "<<o<<endl;
            cin>>array[i][o];
            if(i+1==cafi && o+1==caco){
                for(int ia = 0; ia <= i; ia++){
                    for(int io = 0; io <= o; io++){
                        cout<<"El valor del elemento situado en la fila "<<ia<<" columna "<<io<<" es:"<<array[ia][io]<<endl;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) las formaciones en espacio de memoria automático requieren que el tamaño sea una constante (un valor conocido en tiempo de compilación) no una variable:

```
int cafi,caco,vael; // cafi y caco son variables.
cout<<"Cantidad de filas que desea"<<endl;
cin>>cafi;
cout<<"Cantidad de columnas que desea"<<endl;
cin>>caco;
for(int i=0; i < cafi; i++){
    int array[cafi][caco]; // Incorrecto, cafi y caco no son valores constantes.
```

Si lo que necesitas es que los valores sean definidos por el usuario, entonces tu formación debe ir en espacio de memoria dinámico, es decir: debes usar el operador `new` para crear memoria dinámica:

```
int cafi,caco,vael;

cout<<"Cantidad de filas que desea"<<endl;
cin>>cafi;

cout<<"Cantidad de columnas que desea"<<endl;
cin>>caco;

// Pedimos memoria para las filas.
int **array = new int*[cafi];
// Pedimos memoria para las columnas.
for (int i = 0; i != cafi; ++i)
    array[i] = new int[caco];

for (int i = 0; i != cafi; ++i) {
    // ...
```

No olvides que cuando ya no uses esa memoria, deberás liberarla en sentido inverso a como la pediste:

```
// Liberamos las columnas
for (int i = 0; i != cafi; ++i)
    delete[] array[i];
// Liberamos las filas.
delete[] array;
```

#### Propuesta.

Deja de usar formaciones, usa `std::vector`:

```
unsigned long cafi, caco;

cout << "Cantidad de filas que desea"<<endl;
cin >> cafi;

cout << "Cantidad de columnas que desea"<<endl;
cin >> caco;

auto array = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(cafi, std::vector<int>(caco));

// Leer datos.
int f{};
for (auto &fila : array)
{
    int c{};
    for (auto &valor : fila)
    {
        cout << "Valor del elemento situado en la fila " << f << " columna " << c << '\n';
        cin >> valor;
        ++c;
    }
    ++f;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJNT8MwDD3Pv8IaEts0YOMbbV0vXOHKiYuVuFOk1BlNioSm/XVKkjINgYBL4tjPfu@5VZvNqbIk6647MqJsqxkL43xomOoSDrlXVsE1JYCRgDUZGU9gC4PWG1mjUM1@Q4rRB72EmBZv1sIarYtlRZU5iadyqaZcG7AocHhPEowmjXF@ZSx5fGk5PjzTsChYtF1GtBEsyzzi12blbFvLP/09ObXBITUNveEqiV0semPF1zhaLMtxr/p7fpwmTSZp1myGD8wNagrOn8Egbaba7iJp5RocZ6rjZAwXPeUEBnFlGacy7ivwlWx8LPImIjAjD3afclWzRbZcs8QOb0JL2iELRorMM0zYKjfsl9LnVDpGzzJa5qn9TjJjTkynKt07SGEVw11v7zH9CHRwmOUqJz7gr@5@YP401heTOBztJexrn3qTloZD2wjOl7Druku4hDmcw0W8r@AabuAW7uBdVZbWvjuNX2ylptML@gA)</kbd>.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Evita incluir cabeceras que no usas: no estás usando nada de las cabecera `<locale.h>` ni `<Windows.h>`.
- Usa las cabeceras adecuadas: la cabecera `<locale.h>` pertenece al lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c), si la necesitas en un programa C++ deberías usar su versión adaptada a dicho lenguaje `<clocale>`, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más del tema.
- Procura no abusar de la cláusula `using namespace`, si realmente necesitas usarla hazlo en el ámbito lo más pequeño posible (por ejemplo: en el cuerpo de la función), lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber más del tema.
- Procura no abusar de `std::endl`, esa orden es necesaria en contadas ocasiones y no debería usarse indiscriminadamente, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/14969/2742) para saber más del tema.
- Favorece el pre-incremento frente al post-incremento, lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber más del tema.
- Deja a tu código respirar: No hay necesidad de apretujar todas las líneas y todos los operadores.

Comment: Me parece curioso que la respuesta que aceptaron, quitando los headers windows.h y locale.h, compila y ejecuta sin problemas (g++/c++ 14). Llevo parte de la noche rompiendome la cabeza de por qué inicializa `array`.

Comment: @aeportugal echa un vistazo a los hilos sobre [Formaciones de Tamaño Variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+vla) para responder a esa duda.